# What is the symbolism of the statues and the meeting at the Pantheon in "The Doomed City"?

Tags: russian-language, strugatsky-brothers, the-doomed-city

In part 5 of Strugastkys' *The Doomed City*, when Andrei and his group find the central square, there are countless empty places where statues used to be, and all of them have strange writings.

Later the missing statues turn out to be in the Pantheon, where Andrei delivers a speech about... greatness? For some reason, the statues turn away from him to another speaker.

1. What are the statues?
2. Why the speech? What did it represent?
3. Who was the other speaker?

Comment: If anyone is interested, in [the 19th question in this interview (in Russian)](http://www.rusf.ru/abs/int_t03.htm), Boris Strugatsky says the wiritngs on the bases of the statues do not have any meaning.